# ReactNative - Webview not executing injectedJavaScript on Android

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I'm having trouble getting the Webview on ReactNative to execute the injected JavaScript on a physical Android device. I've scoured the web as far as I could over the past 2 days and still haven't found a solution. Results for testing are as follows:

1. iOS simulator - *All good*
2. iPhone - *All good*
3. Android simulator - *All good*
4. Physical devices, Sony Xperia Z2, Sony Xperia Z5 Compact and LG G4 - **NOTHING**

My Webview is defined as follows:

```
<WebView
  style={styles.webView}
  source={{
    html: html,
    baseUrl: 'web/'
  }}
  injectedJavaScript={'render(' + JSON.stringify(this.state.data) + ');'}
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  bounces={false}
  renderLoading={() => <LoadingIndicator />}
/>
```

I've tried specifying `javaScriptEnabled` as well, to no avail. I also tried smaller scripts to just colour elements on the page or post a message back to the app using `window.postMessage`, but nothing happens. I need to inject the data to the HTML, which will render graphs for me based on the supplied data. My last resort is to manually construct the HTML with the data appended as part of the markup being supplied to the Webview, but I'd really like to keep it simple and just get it to **work the way it should**.

I'm using the latest version of ReactNative (0.41) and the phones are running Android 6+.

Comment: I've had this issue before and what I've found is that Android javascript code needs to be written in strict mode. Anything else and it will be unreliable.

Comment: @wmcbain So what would you recommend? Adding "use strict" before my code snippet that I'm injecting to the page, or adding it before the script that's already on the page (as part of `html`)? Or both? I'll see if I can get around to testing both those scenarios...

Comment: I'm sorry I misspoke. What I found is that Android javascript code needs to be well formatted. Such as `;` at the end of lines & function calls.

Comment: @wmcbain Hmmm... My code is well formatted and all lines are properly terminated. I guess I'll have to just inject the whole script bulk onto the page and ignore the injectedJavascript.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, it was a frustrating problem for me as well. Might be worthwhile to see what people say about Android web views.

Comment: @wmcbain No worries, thanks for attempting to help. Seems like I'm not getting close to an answer, so I had to inject the script manually into the HTML being fed to the Webview. I'll leave the question unanswered until someone offers some insight into why it's not working or how to get the script injected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after leaving this question open for some time and finding a (not so elegant) solution to the problem, I decided I'd share what I ended up doing:

1. I declared the HTML to be passed to the WebView in a constant string along these lines: `const html = '<html>...<script>...[INJECTEDSCRIPT]</script></html>';`
2. I retrieved the data in the `componentDidMount()` event of the React component's lifecycle and set a state variable for it using `this.setState({ data: retrievedData });`
3. This, of course, forced the component to re-render itself, after which I now have the data available to "pass" to the WebView
4. Seeing as I couldn't find any elegant or usable way of using the `injectedJavaScript` property to work the way I want it to (as stated in the question), I resorted to replacing the `[INJECTEDSCRIPT]` value in the HTML constant with the serialized data.

Not the most elegant solution, I know, but it's the only one I could get working reliably across a multitude of devices and emulator configurations. Sample, edited for brevity, as below:

```
const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>...</body>
  <script>
    var render = function (data) {
      ...
    };
    [INJECTEDSCRIPT]
  </script>
</html>`;

export class GraphComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    SERVICE.getData().done((data) => {
      this.setState({ data: data });
    });
  }
  render = () => {
    if (!this.state.data)
      return <LoadingIndicator />;
    let serializedData = JSON.stringify(this.state.data);
    return
      <WebView
        style={styles.webView}
        source={{
          html: html.replace('[INJECTEDSCRIPT]', 'render(' + serializedData + ');'),
          baseUrl: 'web/'
        }}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        bounces={false}
        renderLoading={() => <LoadingIndicator />}
      />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @FarligOpptreden!

I have been struggling to get Javascript (pre-embed and injected) to be executed as well. So far, a simple and better solution is to use `WebViewBridge`. After, everything worked as expected.
      
Here a link to the package: https://cnpmjs.org/package/react-native-webview-bridge

Comment: @MoneroJeanniton it might be possible that the issue is either resolved or that your suggestion works better in latest versions of ReactNative. The problem I faced (and solved with my rudimentary solution) was more than 18 months ago. :)

Answer (score 8):

I just discovered that the Android WebView appears to inject any JS as **a single line**, even if it includes line breaks. That means that missing semicolons can definitely cause issues, or, in my case, comments delimited by `//`. Using `/*` and `*/` for comments got my injected JavaScript working again.

Comment: It didn't work for my scenario. If you have a look at the OP, you'll see that I only did a single function call, passing a JSON object as parameter to it. The function call was terminated by a semicolon as well.

Comment: Good point; I didn't read closely enough. :-) Also, I see, I ran into problems on the emulator and not just real devices.

Comment: So you couldn't get the script to inject on the emulator, but it worked on physical devices? As I stated in the OP, I had the exact opposite experience - the emulator worked perfectly, but it failed miserably on all devices I tested on. Hence my solution of building up the HTML passed to the webview to simulate script injection...

Comment: That's really great help, I was having same issue. Didn't know about single line!

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling to get Javascript (pre-embed and injected) to be executed as well. So far, a simple and better solution is to use WebViewBridge. After, everything worked as expected. Here a link to the package: cnpmjs.org/package/react-native-webview-bridge.

Here a demo:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';

 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

 import {
     Platform,
     WebView,
     ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native'; 

import WevViewBridge from 'react-native-webview-bridge';

// TODO: Keep in mind that you should ALWAYS edit
//       two separate file and keep them matched.
const IOS_WEB_PAGE_SOURCE = './webPage/wordBody.html';
const ANDROID_WEB_PAGE_SOURCE = 'file:///android_asset/webPage/wordBody.html';

export default class WordBody extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }

    _injectedScript = `
        (function(){
            let data = ${JSON.stringify(this.props.data)};
            refresh(data);
        })();
    `;

    render() {
        /*
         * We are using Platform.select here for two reasons:
         * 0. Everythig work fine for IOS using `WebView` from RN
         * 1. Android doesn't load web ressource with `require`
         * 2. On Android, `WebView` from react-native doesn't
         *    execute JavaScript so we use `WebViewBridge`. 
         */
        return Platform.select({
            ios: (<WebView
                    style = {{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', flex:1,}}
                    scalesPageToFit
                    source = {require(IOS_WEB_PAGE_SOURCE)}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    originWhitelist={['*']}
                    injectedJavaScript = {this._injectedScript}
                    renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator/>}
                />),
            android: (<WevViewBridge
                        style = {{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', flex:1,}}
                        scalesPageToFit
                        source = {{uri:ANDROID_WEB_PAGE_SOURCE}}
                        javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        // originWhitelist={['*']}
                        injectedJavaScript = {this._injectedScript}
                        renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator/>}
                    />)
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, webview-bridge is already part of react-native core